# iOS how to export video from PHAsset faster?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to upload video from the album, so I use Phasset to fetch the video source, I am going to export video from PHAsset to sandbox, in which the video will be compressed by different rate. I found the duration of export video too long in high rate. so I am looking for a faster way to export video but without lose the video's rate.

here is my video, 500M, takes me about a half minute to export in the highest rate.

or is there any other way to upload the video in album directly without export?

here is my way to export:

```
    PHVideoRequestOptions* options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
    options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;
    options.deliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
    options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset* avasset, AVAudioMix* audioMix, NSDictionary* info){
        // NSLog(@"Info:\n%@",info);
        AVURLAsset *videoAsset = (AVURLAsset*)avasset;
        // NSLog(@"AVAsset URL: %@",myAsset.URL);
        [self startExportVideoWithVideoAsset:videoAsset presetName:presetName success:success failure:failure];
    }];


- (void)startExportVideoWithVideoAsset:(AVURLAsset *)videoAsset presetName:(NSString *)presetName success:(void (^)(NSString *outputPath))success failure:(void (^)(NSString *errorMessage, NSError *error))failure {
// Find compatible presets by video asset.
NSArray *presets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:videoAsset];

// Begin to compress video
// Now we just compress to low resolution if it supports
// If you need to upload to the server, but server does't support to upload by streaming,
// You can compress the resolution to lower. Or you can support more higher resolution.
if ([presets containsObject:presetName]) {
    AVAssetExportSession *session = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:videoAsset presetName:presetName];
    
    NSDateFormatter *formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss-SSS"];
    // NSLog(@"video outputPath = %@",outputPath);
    NSString *outputPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@output-%@.mp4",
                            [UserCenterUtiles TempVideoPath],
                            [formater stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    session.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputPath];
    
    // Optimize for network use.
    session.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true;
    
    NSArray *supportedTypeArray = session.supportedFileTypes;
    if ([supportedTypeArray containsObject:AVFileTypeMPEG4]) {
        session.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    } else if (supportedTypeArray.count == 0) {
        if (failure) {
            failure(@"No supported file types", nil);
        }
        NSLog(@"No supported file types");
        return;
    } else {
        session.outputFileType = [supportedTypeArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/tmp"]]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/tmp"] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    }
    
    AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [self fixedCompositionWithAsset:videoAsset];
    if (videoComposition.renderSize.width) {
        session.videoComposition = videoComposition;
    }
    
    // Begin to export video to the output path asynchronously.
    [session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            switch (session.status) {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown: {
                    NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown");
                }  break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting: {
                    NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting");
                }  break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting: {
                    NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting");
                }  break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: {
                    NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
                    if (success) {
                        success(outputPath);
                    }
                }  break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: {
                    NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");
                    if (failure) {
                        failure(@"export failed", session.error);
                    }
                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"XMVideoOutputNoticeKey" object:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:session.progress]];
                }  break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled: {
                    NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled");
                    if (failure) {
                        failure(@"export canceled", nil);
                    }
                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"XMVideoOutputNoticeKey" object:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:session.progress]];
                }  break;
                default: break;
            }
        });
    }];
} else {
    if (failure) {
        NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"the device not support export"];
        failure(errorMessage, nil);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If your destination requires a certain format, you may be bound to an undesirable lengthy operation. You may provide a better user experience by uploading the video in the desired format and quality in a URLSession  _background task_. So, the user can even terminate the app, and the system handles the upload over the network. That is, reading the video, converting and compressing it and uploading it will be perceived as a single asynchronous task from the user, which is finished at some time in the future.

Comment: thx your suggestion, I just export and upload in the background task, that is all I can do to provide better user experience.But I found that the competitor app do this operation very very fast,  it is so fast that seems like they just upload without export operation, I don't know how.

Comment: Of course you can just upload the source file without "export" (aka compression, conversion). The question is, what type of video format and quality does the destination require. Also, if you upload the source directly, it may be in high quality and thus the size is large and the upload may take longer. If a user could set these options, that would be nice.

Comment: haha, how to just upload the source file which is in album, that 's good solution for me. we do not care the file size too much right now, so the compression is meaningless for me, can you tell me how to do that,  thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that on iOS, videos are in HEVC format by default. If you have control about the capturing of the videos, you may choose another format, for example in the format you upload it. If your source format and destination format are not the same, it will be transcoded in `AVAssetExportSession`.

Comment: Another note: if you set `session.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse` to `true`, you basically allow AVAssetExportSession to download the asset from iCloud if they are not locally available. The quality may be set to "low", depending on the network bandwidth. So, in order to get better reliable results, you should make sure, the asset exists locally. Of course, when downloading from iCloud is required, this may take a long time.

Comment: thx a lot, I understand it much better now. format is the key matter for whether to transcode. in my case I found a way to get video file:NSFileManager's copyItemAtPath: which does not transcode the format but fast.